Is coverage info in libfuzzer block coverage or branch coverage?
I am running libfuzzer with a target. The log looks like below (an example):
#1      INITED cov: 18 ft: 15 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb
#15     NEW    cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 4 MS: 4 InsertByte-...
#262144 pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 131072 rss: 45Mb
#524288 pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 131072 rss: 62Mb
#1048576        pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 116508 rss: 97Mb
#2097152        pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 110376 rss: 167Mb
#4194304        pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 107546 rss: 306Mb
#8388608        pulse  cov: 23 ft: 16 corp: 2/5b exec/s: 106184 rss: 584Mb

Is the cov:? number block coverage of branch/edge coverage?  I searched many articles and chatgpt, but none of them give same answer. Also, the libfuzzer official page said: Total number of code blocks or edges covered by executing the current corpus.
